# Rails multiple objects select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an index page where I am listing out all the objects(post) from a collection of objects(@posts) which has come from a post controller.

I want to add a checkbox to each of those post objects so that the user can select which one of these objects they want to export via an export controller I have created.

How can I setup a form so that it posts the selected object id's to this export controller?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the checkboxes to be an array. Print out your posts so it looks like the HTML below.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="post_ids[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="post_ids[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="post_ids[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="post_ids[]" value="4" />
```

Then, in the Controller, you can read the values like this on your submit route:

```
post_ids = params[:post_ids]
```

Instead of writing the HTML myself I would look at for example "collection_check_boxes" from rails helpers.

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
In your html.erb write:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "selected_posts[]", post.id %>
<% end %>
```

This will return you an array of ids of posts in your controller for which the check-box was selected. Like this:

```
params[:selected_posts]
```

Which will return you [1, 11, 23 ..] for example.